# Checkbox RadioButton behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, openlayers

I'm trying to implement bootstrap theme into new style for OpenLayers Layer Switcher control.
In bootstrap examples,I have noticed that **input** elements are nested within **label** elements like this:

```
<label class="radio span2">
    <input type="radio" value="option1">
    Cash
</label>
<label class="radio span2">
    <input type="radio" value="option2">
    Invoice
</label>
<label class="radio span2">
    <input type="radio" value="option3">
    Discover
</label>
```

It seems that when you click on the label of a radio button, it gets checked but not triggered. But when you click on the radio itself, it does get triggered. The same thing happens with **checkboxes**.But even if checkboxes are hit checked,click event is not triggered this time.

You can check out the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/myra/RkaJt/)

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have registered a `click` event handler for your controls. If you don't click on a control the handler will not be called.

When a label is associated with an element, then a click on it will 'activate' the element. In case of a checkbox or radio button this means check / checked it.

Checkboxes can also be changed by other means, e.g. keyboard. So a `click` event handler is not the best choice. Use the `change` event instead.

Comment: You're right,I disabled all registered events and activated onchange event of radio buttons,now it's fine.Thank you